# Convert object to string while join array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I want to convert array to string & if array contain object then need to convert in string.

```
array = [
  'a',
  'b',
  { name: 'John doe', age: 25 }
]
```

My code:

`const convertedArray = array.join(' ');`

Output like below:

a b "{"name":"john", "age":22, "class":"mca"}"

Comment: How the `class` property should be created? From your snippet it's unclear. If you want to just convert object to string - you can use `JSON.stringify(object)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array reduce function. Inside the reduce callback check if the current object which is under iteration is an object or not. If it is an object then use `JSON.stringify` and concat with the accumulator.

```js
const array = [
  'a',
  'b',
  {
    name: 'John doe',
    age: 25
  }
];

const val = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  if (typeof curr === 'object') {
    acc += JSON.stringify(curr);
  } else {
    acc += `${curr} `

  }


  return acc;
}, '');
console.log(val)
```

Using JSON.stringify on the entire `array` will have starting and ending `[` and `]` respectively, which is not what you are looking

```js
const array = [
  'a',
  'b',
  {
    name: 'John doe',
    age: 25
  }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple ! Try following :

```
var arr = [
  'a',
  'b',
  { name: 'John doe', age: 25 }
]

var newArr = arr.map(i => typeof i === "object" ? JSON.stringify(i) : i)

console.log(newArr)
```

output :

```
['a', 'b', '{"name":"John doe","age":25}']
```